# Jobs Not Queuing (E-Mails Sending Immediately)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently running into an issue where my e-mails are not queuing in Laravel 5.8.

I have run:

```
php artisan queue:table 
php artisan migrate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Controller:

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(2);

$customer->notify((new CustomerOrderItemStatusNotification($orderItem))->delay($when));
```

.env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

queue.php:

```
'connections' => [
    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ]
]
```

CustomerOrderItemStatusNotification:

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class CustomerOrderItemStatusNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
```

**The issue is that it is sending this immediately rather than waiting two minutes nor is it storing anything in the 'jobs' table.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

implement class to shouldQueue interface

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CustomerOrderItemStatusNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
```